# django-rest-framework: generic view and method-based permission

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to apply authentication to only one method of generic view? I have a generic `ListCreateAPIView` and I want to apply authentication to `get` method and only grant permission while `IsAuthenticated` but let the `post` method respond without authentication?

In function-based views this can be done quite easily by adding a decorator to each method. But I don't know how to do it with class based views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it is to write custom permission:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework import generics

class IsAuthenticatedNotPost(IsAuthenticated):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            return True
        return super(IsAuthenticatedNotPost, self).has_permission(request, view)

class SomeView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedNotPost, )
```

Comment: I was thinking to override `perform_authentication` on generic views and check the `request.method` there. But this is cool.Thanks.